# How To Exclude MariaDB From remi repository?

Tags: repository, mariadb, centos7

I have a problem when going to install the latest MariaDB on CentOS 7. I use yum repository from MariaDB, for only mariadb, another module like php use remirepo. I added a yum repo for MariaDB-10 but installed always mariadb-55.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: MariaDB-common conflicts with 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.52-1.el7
           Installed: MariaDB-shared-10.1.21-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (@mariadb)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:10.1.21-1.el7.centos
Error: Package: 1:mariadb-server-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:5.5.52-1.el7
           Installed: MariaDB-shared-10.1.21-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (@mariadb)
               mariadb-libs(x86-64) = 1:10.1.21-1.el7.centos
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Also i have exclude option on remi.repo

> /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo

```
## Exclude following Packages Updates ##
exclude=mariadb-server mariadb mariadb-libs MariaDB-common MariaDB-client
```

Answer (score 0):

mariadb doesn't not come from "remi" repository, but from base/updates standard repositories.

Comment: Sorry, 

Do you can help me disable mariadb repo from base?

Comment: Please update your question title which is not correct. 
The "exclude" directive  in the correct repo file should work.